# github.io root wont render index.html automatically

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have created a site in github.io by properly having a project called jaimegarza.github.io in github (a fork of barryclark/jekyll-now project.) It has an index.html page in it. When I try https://jaimegarza.github.io it tells me that "There isn't a Github Pages yet". I have edited and pushed to it.

However, if I try https://jaimegarza.github.io/index.html it shows.

I cannot find any setting that will indicate that index.html should be used as root, or anything related to that.

Have you seen this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. It just took ONE hour for it to work!